# Web App: Fluid Resizing but keep certain space constant

Tags: html, css

I had a fixed web page layout. When I expanded the window, the different elements of course stayed put.

[image]

I've managed to fix it so that the elements move with the resizing of the window.In this example, I only changed the code for JFK and Laguardia.
[image]
As you can see, the distance between the elements increases. I'd like for the space between the boxes("JFK" and "LAGUARDIA") to remain the same even as the boxes shift across the page. How can I specify the space between these elements?

```
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #c4d8e2;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", Helvetica Neue, serif;
}


.page-title {
    position: relative;
    top: -3%:
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: lighter;  
    margin-left:5%;
}

.JFK {
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
    height: 300px; 
    width: 300px; 
    bottom: 40px;
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    display: block; 
}

.JFK h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;

}


.JFK p{
    position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    display: none;
}

.JFK p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}


.JFK:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.JFK:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}



.Laguardia {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    top: -410px;
    left: 70%; 
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center; 
}


.Laguardia h6{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;

}

.Laguardia p{
    position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c4d8e2;
    display: none;
}

.Laguardia p a{
    color: #c4d8e2;
    top: -30px;
}

.Laguardia:hover p {
    display: block;
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
}


.Laguardia:hover{
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header> 
       <h1 class = "page-title">Ride Share</h1>
       <nav>
           <ul>
               <li>home</li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                   <button class="dropbtn">create a ride</button>
                   <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <li>login</li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    <div class = "JFK">
        <h6>JFK</h6>
        <div class = "transbox">
           <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
           <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "Laguardia"> 
        <h6>LAGUARDIA</h6>
        <p> 
             <a href = "#">to</a>
             <a href = "#">from</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "Newark">
       <h6>NEWARK</h6>
       <p> 
           <a href = "#">to</a>
           <a href = "#">from</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class = "Create-Ride">
        <h6>CREATE A RIDE</h6>
        <p> 
            <a href = "#">to</a>
            <a href = "#">from</a></p>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you try `margin-left` property

Comment: You shouldn't be setting `left` as a percentage of the width of the screen. As the screen resizes, the difference between 70% (Laguardia) and 30% will increase or decrease. What you *should* do is look into either `display: inline-block`, `display: flex`, or `float: left`. Unfortunately, you'll need to change quite a bit of your structure to get those to work, but it will be well worth it in the long run. Start from a template, and then work from there :)

Comment: When I make one element display: inline-block, to get the hover element and the text element on the box line up like they did before -- do i also need to set those to display:inline-block....or?